# Data extracting from REST API in loop

Tags: informatica

I am extracting data from REST API in Informatica powercenter using http transformation.

In my source API body there is a offset and rowcount limitation hence I need to extract the data in chunks.
Is there way to extract the source data in loop.

For example, If the source API contains 200 records then can we extract first 100 records and then perform a loop to extract next set of records.

Please let me know the best way to achieve above requirement.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options -

1. Create a shell/batch script to loop through .

- Create a workflow which will call HTTP transformation. This will accept two parameters - start_range and end_range.
- Script will supply start and end value and increment it for each loop. it will use pmcmd to kick the workflow and will wait till it finishes.
- The shell script will be scheduled.
  Use this approach when you dont know how many times you have to run.

2. Put the HTTP in a mapping and a session which accept two parameters - start_range and end_range.. Reuse this session as many times as you want and pass different range using parameter file. If your total row count is low and  you know possible max value you can do this.
3. Use Java transformation to call the HTTP transformation in loop and pass start_range and end_range. Personally i havent used this approach so i am not sure but this can be used if you can call the HTTP using java.